# Excel Worksheet assignment in VB.Net doesn't compile

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm converting a VB6 application into VB.Net and having trouble with the basics. I start off with:-

```
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim xlsheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlwbook As Excel.Workbook

xl = New Excel.Application
xlwbook = xl.Workbooks.Open(my_data.file_name)
xlsheet = xlwbook.Sheets(1)
```

but the last line doesn't compile; it reports

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversion from 'Object' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet'

I can make this go away by replacing the line with

```
xlsheet = CType(xlwbook.Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
```

but that does't look like the right thing to do to me. If the assignment is correct, I would have thought the object should naturally have the correct type.

So: does anyone know what the correct thing I should be doing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible without a conversion of type (If Option Strict Is On) because .NET cannot understand a VBA Collection.

I believe [this bug report](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323737) is *related* to the issue:

If you have a look at the Excel Example on [this page (Converting Code from VBA to Visual Basic .NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa192490%28v=office.11%29.aspx), then it shows this code:

```
Dim ThisWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet = _
        CType(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Item("Sheet1"), Excel.Worksheet)
```

There have been several post about this issue like [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/921a6de1-364b-4b0d-9d5b-334aa30db022) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/Vsexpressvb/thread/8d158701-8477-4c50-9885-257df0e29c54) but there doesn't seem to be a better way round it.

Comment: Thanks. I've set Option Strict Off, which has a similar effect. I can't say I like it very much, but if it has to be done, it has to be done.

Comment: I would personally recommend leaving Option Strict On and doing a type conversion - this has to be safer in the long run.