# Not able to extract value from a particular cell in excel sheet

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-interop, excel-automation

I am trying to access the cell `A7` of an excel file which has only one excel sheet. However i am getting the following error `Public member 'Range' on type '__ComObject' not found.` in the statement `Dim tempValue As String = owb.Worksheets(1).Range("A7") 'Error`. Why does this error come and how to correct it? Btw, I also tried using the `Value` and `Value2` after `Range` in the above statement but even that does not work - surprisingly the `value` and `value2` do not appear in intellisense after `Range` in the error statement in the code.

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Module Program
    Dim oxl As Excel.Application
    Dim owb As Excel.Workbook
    Sub Main()
        oxl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        oxl.Visible = True
        Dim path As String = "G:\Amit Kapoor\Matthews Asia\Matthews Raw Data"
        Dim names As String() = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xlsx")
        Dim pathofFirstfile As String = names(0)
        Console.WriteLine(pathofFirstfile) 'Works fine
        owb = oxl.Workbooks.Open(pathofFirstfile)  'Works fine
        Dim tempValue As String = owb.Worksheets(1).Range("A7") 'Error
        Console.WriteLine("Scheme Name: {0}", tempValue)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Another related question is as follows: In the above code, I have pointed at the excel workbook with the variable `oxl` by using `oxl` to open the excel file. However, if I open it, I have to close it also - that increases the length of my code. So is there any way to associate the variable `oxl` with the excel workbook in order to execute excel tasks without opening the excel workbook? That is, is it possibe to make `oxl` point to the desired excel workbook without opening the workbook using the variable `oxl`?

Comment: your putting a range object to a string? (not sure if vb.net is ok with this, but vba would definitely not be pleased!)

Comment: @NickSlash I am getting the same error even if I write `Dim tempValue As String = Cstr(owb.Worksheets(1).Range("A7"))` or `Dim tempValue As Object = owb.Worksheets(1).Range("A7")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont have VB installed so cant test, looking at examples etc it looks like you need to explicitly cast some things for it to work properly?

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Module Program
    Dim oxl As Excel.Application
    Dim owb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ows As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim owr As Excel.Range
    Sub Main()
        oxl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        oxl.Visible = True
        Dim path As String = "G:\Amit Kapoor\Matthews Asia\Matthews Raw Data"
        Dim names As String() = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xlsx")
        Dim pathofFirstfile As String = names(0)
        Console.WriteLine(pathofFirstfile)
        owb = oxl.Workbooks.Open(pathofFirstfile)
        ows = CType(owb.Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
        owr = ows.Range("A7")
        Dim tempValue As String = CStr(owr.Value)
        Console.WriteLine("Scheme Name: {0}", tempValue)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: surprisingly this works. Any reason for this to work or should I follow this as convention? Also, any thoughts on my second question - that is, is it possible to associate `oxl` to the excel workbook without opening it?

Comment: @JoyG cant say for sure, looks like certain things (collections specifically) are not returned from interop in a way that VB.net understands? see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11308419/212869

Comment: as for the second, im not totally sure what you mean. the excel app shouldn't need to be visible but it will have to be open for interop to work.